# Symfony 2 - logging in a service

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

novice to symfony so please point anything out obvious :)

I have a service that sends push notifications. I am trying to pass a logging obj to that service so that i can write to the main log handler.
bottom line is this does not write anywhere and i have no idea where i've gone wrong.

I took some things out of my code but this is generally the idea.

blah\CoreBundle\Service\PushTask.php

```
public function __construct(
   \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager,
    $logger
) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
...
public function pushSomething() 
{
    $this->logger->addInfo('test');   // not writing
}
```

config_dev.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: info
```

blah\CoreBundle\Resources\config\services.xml

```
<service id="civix_core.push" class="blah\CoreBundle\Service\PushTask">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete stack you can use following your example:

blah\CoreBundle\Service\PushTask.php

```
/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
private $logger;

public function __construct(
   \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
...
public function pushSomething() 
{
    $this->logger->info('test');
}
```

config.yml

```
monolog:
  channels:
    - your_new_channel
  handlers:
    // just keep it or add a new handler like:
    your_handler:
      type:   stream
      path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_new_channel.log"
      level:  info
      channels: ["your_new_channel"]
```

blah\CoreBundle\Resources\config\services.xml

```
<service id="civix_core.push" class="blah\CoreBundle\Service\PushTask">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <argument type="service" id="monolog.logger.your_new_channel" />
</service>
```

Go check the file: dev_new_channel.log

You can also clear your cache after doing this in order to make sure all the yml/xml changes are in place!

Why is this my suggestion?
Using channel and handlers will help you maintain your log organized and with easy changes!

Comment: thank you for the response. when i can i'll check this out tonight. this appears to be the direction i was headed down just didn't have a _complete_ understanding just yet. i'll keep you posted!

Comment: it looks like this is config for monolog 2.4. i'm using 2.3. sorry i did not specify. this has got me on the right track just still fumbling over the proper setup in the config.

Comment: If you don't have any specific reason for staying in old versions I recommend you to update it!

Comment: @au_stan if you managed to make it to work don't forget to choose the right answer!

Comment: not sure of any issues with an upgraded logger but will probably have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$this->logger->info('test');
```

instead of this:

```
$this->logger->addInfo('test');
```

Hope this help (ASAP more info).

Comment: thanks for the response @matteo . will try that but i'm pretty sure i've tried your suggestion. that was my initial attempt but tried `addInfo()` only because i've seen in done else where. i was/am desperate. ha! i'll update asap.

Answer (score -2):

```
public function getCustomerAction(Request $request){ 
 Common::Init($this->get('logger'),$request->headers->get('Request-id'));}

class Common {

    public static $logger;
    public static $request_id;



    public static function Init($logger, $request_id) {

        self::$logger = $logger;


        //  self::$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stderr', Logger::DEBUG));



        if (is_null($request_id)) {
           self::$request_id = Common::generate_uuid();
        }
        else{
          self::$request_id  =$request_id;
        }

          self::$logger->pushProcessor(function ( $record) {

           $record['context']['request-id'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID'] : self::$request_id;
           dump($record);
           return $record;
        });

         Common::$logger->debug('hey it works');



    }


    public static function generate_uuid() {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x', mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000, mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000, mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }}
```

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your approach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.